# Text-align: center doesn't work for social divs

Tags: html, css, centering

I would like to have my 4 social pictures (`alt=test`) in the center of my div (now they are appearing on the top center). I put `text-align: center` in `.socials` but it is not working. I also tried to put it in `.socialdivs` but it is also not working. The HTML and CSS code is below.

```css
.socials {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e6066;
  text-align: center;
}

.socialdivs {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.fb {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 155px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fb:hover {
  background-color: #4668b3;
}

.lin {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.lin:hover {
  background-color: #00a0dc;
}

.insta {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 155px;
  margin: auto;
}

.insta:hover {
  background-color: #405de6;
}

.golden {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 155px;
  margin: auto;
}

.golden:hover {
  background-color: #fcbf17;
}

.info {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="socials">
    <div class="socialdivs">
      <div class="fb">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="test" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="lin">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="test" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="insta">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="test" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="golden">
        <a href="https://www.goldenline.pl" target="_blank"><img src="img/goldenline.png" alt="test" /></a>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    Adrian &copy; 2017 Thank you for your visit!
  </div>
</footer>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `text-align` only works on `inline` or `inline-block` elements. A html div is `block` by default.

Comment: This thing will work in your case **top: 50%;position: relative;** put this css on anchor tag and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height: 155px;` to center it vertically. It needs to have the same height as the container. So, when the height of the container change, the line-height needs to be adjusted.

```css
.socials
{
 width:100%;
 background-color: #5e6066;
 text-align: center;
    line-height: 155px;
}

.socialdivs
{
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
}

.fb
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 250px;
 height: 155px;
 margin: auto;
}

.fb:hover
{
 background-color: #4668b3;
}

.lin
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 250px;
 height: 155px;
 margin-top: auto;
}

.lin:hover
{
 background-color: #00a0dc;
}

.insta
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 250px;
 height: 155px;
 margin: auto;
}

.insta:hover
{
 background-color: #405de6;
}

.golden
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 250px;
 height: 155px;
 margin: auto;
}

.golden:hover
{
 background-color: #fcbf17;
}

.info
{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <footer>
        <div class="socials">
   <div class="socialdivs">
    <div class="fb">
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="test" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="lin">
     <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="test" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="insta">
     <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="test" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="golden">
     <a href="https://www.goldenline.pl" target="_blank"><img src="img/goldenline.png" alt="test" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info">
   Adrian &copy; 2017 Thank you for your visit!
  </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: it is almost what I want but the pics are still not in the middle: https://ibb.co/f9aqAm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding` to set text in middle of div,(along with `text-align:center;`) like this:

```
.socialdivs
{
    padding: 10%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code and this is what happens: https://ibb.co/mv62O6 I need to keep it in 1 line

Answer (score 0):

padding and margin by default show a good result in anchor tag so use display block in it